# Union Iterative through Columns/Transfroms Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been asked to create a query transforming data from something like the 1st image, with standard rows/columns

```
Year       Company     Completed        DayofWeek    Hour        Country        
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2022          A            Y             Mon           12         France
2019          A            N             Tue           14         Germany
2022          A            Y             Thu           13          Italy
2021          B            N             Sat           16          France
2022          B            Y             Mon           14           Spain
2021          B            Y             Tue           12           France
```

To something like the below where a number of the field names are on 1 column and the field values are in another

```
       Company     Completed     Field Name    Field Value    Total        
---------------------------------------------------------------------
          A            Y          DayofWeek          Mon        50
          A            Y          DayofWeek          Tue        35
          A            N          DayofWeek          Mon        40
          A            N          Hour               16         55
          A            Y          Hour               12         40
          A            Y          Hour               14         30
```

In the actual query there are more columns being transformed.  I'm currently using lots of union statements e.g.

```
select
Company, Completed, 'Day of Week' as 'Field Name', [Day_of_Week] as 'Field Values', count(*) as Total
from Table 1
where year=2022
Group by
Company, Completed, [Day_of_Week]

union all

select
Company, Completed, 'Hour' as 'Field Name', [Hour] as 'Field Values', count(*) as Total
from Table 1
where year =2022
Group by
Company, Completed, [Hour]
```

I've been asked to do it this way to output fewer rows and also as customer would like to be able to compare the completed % across all measures at once.

However I feel there could be a more efficient way of doing this to not have so many unions/not manually update each union if changes to script, but haven't found anything - some way of looping through the different columns to add to bottom.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to total? You sample data does not match your expected output. Company A has Mon listed twice (and different totals).

Comment: Apologies - The total would be the number of rows.  So the total in the 2nd table would be the number of rows in the first table
E.g. for Company A, Yes, Day of Week, Mon.  The total is 1 from table 1.  I have put 50 as an example of what it potentially could be.

Comment: No worries. Number of rows Grouped by Company, Completed and column? (i.e. Hour/DayofWeek/Country)?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `CONVERT` the columns you want to unpivot in a subquery (assuming the data type of `Hour, DayofWeek, Country` do not match - they must match for the `PIVOT/UNPIVOT` functions to work).

Then, perform a `UNPIVOT` function to rotate your columns to rows.

The newly created `Field_Value` column from the `UNPIVOT` function will contain your column values and the `Field_Name` will contain your column names (you can change the alias for these columns if you want).

Finally, add a `GROUP BY` to aggregate your data based on `Company`, `Completed`, and your newly created `Field_Name` and `Field_Value` columns in order to get a `COUNT` for your `Total` column.

```
SELECT 
      u.Company, 
      u.Completed, 
      u.Field_Name,
      u.Field_Value,
      COUNT(u.Field_Value) AS Total
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             Company,
             Completed,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DayofWeek) AS DayofWeek,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Hour) AS Hour,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Country) AS Country
          FROM sample_table) pv
    UNPIVOT 
        (Field_Value FOR Field_Name IN (DayofWeek, Hour, Country)) u
    GROUP BY u.Company, u.Completed, u.Field_Name, u.Field_Value
    ORDER BY u.Company, u.Field_Name ASC
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uGcGn161).

**Result:**

| Company | Completed | Field_Name | Field_Value | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | N | Country | Germany | 1 |
| A | Y | Country | France | 1 |
| A | Y | Country | Italy | 1 |
| A | N | DayofWeek | Tue | 1 |
| A | Y | DayofWeek | Mon | 1 |
| A | Y | DayofWeek | Thu | 1 |
| A | N | Hour | 14 | 1 |
| A | Y | Hour | 12 | 1 |
| A | Y | Hour | 13 | 1 |
| B | Y | Country | France | 2 |
| B | Y | Country | Spain | 1 |
| B | Y | DayofWeek | Mon | 1 |
| B | Y | DayofWeek | Sat | 1 |
| B | Y | DayofWeek | Tue | 1 |
| B | Y | Hour | 12 | 1 |
| B | Y | Hour | 14 | 1 |
| B | Y | Hour | 16 | 1 |

***Note that I changed the N flag to Y for the Company B Completed column to show the `GROUP BY` Total working*.

Read more about `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` here from Microsoft:
[FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly what I was after - much appreciated

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer to include more details on how it was done.